# Writing a number 'm' as a sum of 'n' prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, partitions, integer-sequence

We can write {2 = 2}, {3 = 2+1, 3 = 3}, {4 = 2+2, 4 = 3+1}, {5 = 3+2, 5 = 2+2+1}, {6 = 3+3, 6 = 5+1, 6 = 3+2+1} and so on. I am trying to write every positive integer as a sum of Prime numbers.
In general, how can we write a positive integer 'm' as the sum of exactly 'n' prime numbers.
I tried the Integer Partitions but failed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you try with `IntegerPartitions`? Did you try combining the output of that function with `Select` and `PrimeQ`?

Comment: `1` is not considered a prime number.

Comment: No, I didn't try Select & PrimeQ. In fact, I don't know what to do with this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

primePartitions[m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] :=
 IntegerPartitions[m, {n}, Prime /@ Range[PrimePi[m]]]
```

For sum of exactly two or three primes

```
Row[{
  Select[
    {#, Inactive[Plus] @@@ primePartitions[#, 2]} & /@
     Range[20], #[[2]] =!= {} &] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &,
  Spacer[5],
  Select[
    {#, Inactive[Plus] @@@ primePartitions[#, 3]} & /@
     Range[20], #[[2]] =!= {} &] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &}]
```

[image]

**If you want to allow use of `1` in addition to primes**

```
primePartitions2[m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] :=
 IntegerPartitions[m, {n},
  Join[{1}, Prime /@ Range[PrimePi[m]]]]

Column[{
  Select[
    {#, Inactive[Plus] @@@ primePartitions2[#, 2]} & /@
     Range[20], #[[2]] =!= {} &] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &,
  Select[
    {#, Inactive[Plus] @@@ primePartitions2[#, 3]} & /@
     Range[20], #[[2]] =!= {} &] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I should have known that IntegerPartitions had that form.

Comment: It worked. Thanks much.